# React Router unable to render an exact path unless going to root domain first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My app is currently deployed through GitHub pages and is routed to a domain I've purchased. The site works perfectly when going to the domain first. But when trying to go directly to a specific path, a 404 error is returned. I'm not using any type of server, this is more of a display of information. I have been unable to update my routes to correct this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.scss";
import App from "./Components/App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App**

```js
import "./App.scss";
import WelcomePage from "../WelcomePage";
import Nav from "../Nav";
import Career from "../Career";
import Portfolio from "../Portfolio";
import Resume from "../Resume";
import Contact from "../Contact";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <title>Mike Codes</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Nav />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={WelcomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/personal-site" component={WelcomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/career" component={Career} />
        <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
        <Route exact path="/resume" component={Resume} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The idea is to return your `index.html` for any route of your domain. You need to configure htaccess file on your server